# C++ Chocolate Puzzle

Tags: c++, algorithm, puzzle

Let's say I have N chocolates that have to be packed into exactly P boxes in the order they arrive. Each chocolate also has a number of calories X and each box has a capacity K which has to be less than or equal to 3*sum(x1, x2, ..., xn) + max(x1, x2, ..., xn)^2 - min(x1, x2, ..., xn)^2.

In the task I'm given N, P and X for each chocolate and I have to figure out the lowest possible K. Could anyone help me on this (not looking for a solution just for some hints regarding the problem)?

Example:
    N = 8,
    P = 3,
    X = {1, 4, 5, 6, 3, 2, 5, 3}

```
K for first three chocolates = 3*(1+4+5) + 5^2 - 1^2 = 54
K for next two chocolates = 3*(6+3) + 6^2 - 3^2 = 54
K for last three chocolates = 3*(2+5+3) + 5^2 - 2^2  = 51

Lowest possible K = 54
```

So the goal is to find the best combination using exactly P boxes that has the lowest K.

Thanks!

Comment: This looks like a homework problem. Besides, you would want to tag it as "algorithm". This is not language-specific. Last but not least, this looks like a binary search problem with greedy strategy.

Comment: It is but I have no idea how to solve it. Could you please give me some more hints?

Comment: For me this looks like task for "dynamic programming" which are quite usual in TopCoder contests.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is how I would solve this in Java:

```
import java.util.HashMap;
import java.util.Map;
import java.util.Random;

public class ChocolatePuzzle {
    private static final Map <String, Integer> solutions =
        new HashMap <String, Integer> ();

    private static final Map <String, Integer> bestMoves =
            new HashMap <String, Integer> ();

    private static int [] x;

    private static int k (int from, int to)
    {
        int sum = x [from];
        int max = x [from];
        int min = x [from];
        for (int i = from + 1; i < to; i++)
        {
            sum += x [i];
            max = Math.max (max, x [i]);
            min = Math.min (min, x [i]);
        }

        return sum * 3 + max * max - min * min;
    }

    public static int solve (int n, int p)
    {
        String signature = n + "," + p;
        Integer solution = solutions.get (signature);
        if (solution == null)
        {
            solution = Integer.valueOf (doSolve (n, p, signature));
            solutions.put (signature, solution);
        }
        return solution.intValue ();
    }

    public static int doSolve (int n, int p, String signature)
    {
        if (p == 1)
        {
            bestMoves.put (signature, Integer.valueOf (x.length - n));
            return k (n, x.length);
        }
        else
        {
            int result = Integer.MAX_VALUE;
            int bestMove = 0;

            int maxI = x.length - n - p + 1;
            for (int i = 1; i <= maxI; i++)
            {
                int k = Math.max (k (n, n + i), solve (n + i, p - 1));

                if (k < result)
                {
                    result = k;
                    bestMove = i;
                }
            }

            bestMoves.put (signature, Integer.valueOf (bestMove));

            return result;
        }
    }

    public static void main(String[] args) {
        int n = 20;
        int p = 5;
        x = new int [n];

        Random r = new Random ();
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
            x [i] = r.nextInt (9) + 1;

        System.out.println("N: " + n);
        System.out.println("P: " + p);
        System.out.print("X: {");
        for (int i = 0; i < n; i++)
        {
            if (i > 0) System.out.print (", ");
            System.out.print (x [i]);
        }
        System.out.println("}");

        System.out.println();

        int k = solve (0, p);

        int o = 0;
        for (int i = p; i > 0; i--)
        {
            int m = bestMoves.get (o + "," + i);

            System.out.print ("{");
            for (int j = 0; j < m; j++)
            {
                if (j > 0)
                    System.out.print (", ");
                System.out.print (x [o + j]);
            }
            System.out.print ("} (k: ");
            System.out.print(k (o, o + m));
            System.out.println (")");

            o += m;
        }

        System.out.println("min(k): " + k);
    }
}
```

Probably you could find some useful tips in this code.

Sample input:

```
N: 20
P: 5
X: {1, 7, 6, 6, 5, 5, 7, 9, 1, 3, 9, 5, 3, 7, 9, 1, 4, 2, 4, 8}
```

Sample output:

```
{1, 7, 6, 6} (k: 108)
{5, 5, 7, 9} (k: 134)
{1, 3, 9, 5} (k: 134)
{3, 7, 9} (k: 129)
{1, 4, 2, 4, 8} (k: 120)
min(k): 134
```